# Any things like jQuery parseJSON in Android?

Tags: android, json, parsing

The web service return a JSON string like

```
"[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Peter\"}]"
```

In jQuery, I can use `$.parseJSON` to convert it to valid JSON string

```
[{"Id":"1","Name":"Peter"}]
```

Any similar method in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android comes with org.json package to parse json, but there are other libraries that might make it easier to convert to java objects:

comes with android sdk:

- [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)

other downloadble packages:

- [GSON](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)
- [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)